# How can I kill all entities of a specific type, EXCEPT the youngest one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to create armor stands whenever I stand on a certain block, but when I stand on it, it summons a lot of armor stands.

I tried `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,c=!1]` to kill all except the newest one but it killed all of them.

What should I do to remove all except the youngest?

Comment: You have the selector `[type=ArmorStand.c=!1]`, however it should be `[type=ArmourStand,c=!1]` (note comma instead of period), was this a mistake typing or did you also type it this way in the command? Also, I'm not sure if `c=!1` works, I'll have to test it.

Comment: MegaMoh, please don't use tags that are irrelevant to your question, it will get enough interest as it stands.

Comment: @shelvacu `=!` works

Comment: When restricting a selector with `c=`, it selects them in order of distance from the player, not age.

Comment: I made it in minecraft by the comma here I only mistaked and I tried ,c=!1 it does not work so I ask how

Answer (score 3):

Make a scoreboard

```
/scoreboard objectives add age dummy age
```

put a commandblock by a fill clock and type in

```
/execute @e[score_age=0,type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand] age 1
```

put another commandblock by a fill clock and type in

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,score_age=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just kill all the armorstands before you summon a new one